# Save Richtextbox to .txt but same format vb.net2010

Tags: vb.net

when i click the button save, the output of richtextbox1 will be save in .txt,, but my problem is not all the format in richtextbox1 is not desame in .txt that i save. how to fix this?

```
Private Sub ADD_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ADD.Click       
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(OutputTstm.Text & " " & vbNewLine)
    RichTextBox1.AppendText("*********************" + vbNewLine)      
End Sub

Private Sub btnsave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    Dim isave As New SaveFileDialog

    isave.Filter = "txt files (.txt) |*.txt"
    isave.FilterIndex = 2
    isave.RestoreDirectory = False

    If isave.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        IO.File.WriteAllText(isave.FileName, RichTextBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

![Richtextbox1 to Notepad ][1]ck.imgur.com/Lw6gz.png

Comment: I have fixed your code formatting. Now please fix your image. When posting a question, you are provided with a preview for a reason. Please don't submit if that preview makes it clear that you have not entered a clear post.

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` of the `RichTextBox` is just like the `Text` of a regular `TextBox`.  It is the `Rtf` property that contains all the markup and thus all the formatting.

The thing is, you don't need to use either property to save the contents to a file. The `RichTextBox` has a `SaveFile` method that lets you save either plain text or Rich Text Format (RTF).

There is a corresponding `LoadFile` method to read a file into the control.

Also, if you're saving RTFrather than plain text, you should be using the ".rtf" extension rather than ".txt".

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in the RichTextBox Class, that allows saving a file without needing to use a StreamReader.

It's `RichTextBox.SaveFile()`.
There are arguments required by this function, and the ones you need are `RichTextBox.SaveFile(FileName As String, FileType As RichTextBoxStreamType)`

With those arguments, the code you need is `RichTextBox1.SaveFile(isave.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)`